# textview doesn't appear on screen

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

hello guys I have an xml file "registeration form" but when I run it I can't see all the texts in text view..... can some on plz help....I don't think it's in the code as far as I can remember what I did it last time is from  options at the theme option of that xml file

unfortunately I forgot how can some one help me fetch that off my memory plz

here is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#3b3b3b"
tools:context=".RegisterActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- View Title Label -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dip"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:textSize="25dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Name Label -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Full Name" />
    <!-- Name TextField -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Email Label -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email" />
    <!-- Email TextField -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerEmail"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- Password Label -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:text="Password" />
    <!-- Password TextField -->

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/registerPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:password="true" />

    <!-- Error message -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/register_error"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textColor="#e30000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <!-- Login Button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="Register" />

    <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLinkToLoginScreen"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Already registred. Login Me!"
        android:textColor="#21dbd4"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
     </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: set theme to holo.light or holo.black

Comment: if you are using eclipse the theme button appears right next to flip orientation button in graphical view...

Comment: and why you are using scrollview here...can you explain?

Comment: set your theme to theme.black i tried it with your code it it works...

Comment: @Karan Mer them.black dosn't work for me

Comment: try other themes even if it doesnt works then unfortunately you have to set your background to some other color...

Comment: the thing is that last time I changed it and it was great now when I run the project again it changed back!!!!I wonder if anyway I make it this time will it revert at next run after I leave the project a side for a time

Comment: wait...have you tried to refresh and clean your project after setting theme to theme.black...try it and tell what happens

Comment: ok guys I solved already It was that I have defined a theme for my app in my AndroidManifest  file which I guess be as my default app theme...really thanks a lot you allll

Answer (score 1):

change your textview color other than black..if you use xml then set textColor property to say `#FFFFFF.`

Comment: as I said is nothing with my code that's as I did last time but I don't why it changed back!!!

Comment: try with theme->theme.black